# CodeIgniter Email Error

Tags: email, codeigniter

I'm making use of the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) [`Email` class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) to send emails. Unfortunately none of the emails are getting sent - instead, I keep getting this message:

```
We do not authorize the use of this system to transport 
unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

Comment: Without more information its very hard to say, but given the error message you got it seems likely that there is an authentication issue at the SMTP server.

Comment: post you're code as we can't tell witch is the problem .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the **mail** or **Send mail** functions of PHP to send mail. Do note that these functions by default inherit the mail settings of your web hosting server (or local server), and from the looks of your error it seems that your web host does not allow sending email without some kind of verification of your application or some configuration.

This doesn't look like a generic CodeIgniter error, or an SMTP error. Check with your hosting provider, or if you're running on localhost, check your server mail settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending mail with other smtp mail server such as gmail, etc.

Check this: [link text](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/114977/#582023)

If the problem still remain unsolved, please post your code and let us know.